# Are there alternative ways to interface with Mavericks tags?

Tags: macos, finder, finder-tag

My company hosts quite a large amount of reference material (images, video, pdfs) on a server, and we're looking for a good way to organize these assets by tags. Searching for these tags in Finder is very slow.  Are there any other ways to interface with any of these tags/files?

Answer (score 1):

Launchers, like [LaunchBar 6](http://www.obdev.at/products/launchbar/index.html), can be a great way to navigate tags. Type the name of your tag and then right arrow to navigate the files. [Alfred](http://www.alfredapp.com/) may offer something similar.

Answer (score -1):

Just try [Leap](http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/26019/leap): best way to manage finder tags